# Printing to a HP Deskjet 3000 J310 via IPP or similar

Tags: wireless-networking, printer, hp-deskjet

A friend of mine has an HP Deskjet 3000 J310 printer.  She wants to print to it wirelessly, but our university's IT department has disabled/blocked Bonjour/Zeroconf.  I can still access the printer via the hostname and IP address to get to the embedded web server.

Is it possible to connect and print to the printer via IPP, JetDirect, or similar method?

(Another way of thinking about this would be: how would one connect and print to this kind of printer where the printer and computer are on separate subnets?)